# Built-in widget with onTouched and onReleased callbacks?

Tags: flutter

I just started using Flutter a couple of days ago and I’m enjoying it a lot.

I noticed that when I use a `FlatButton`, `onPressed` gets called when the button is touched then released.

Is there a similar widget to `FlatButton` that has a callback when it's touched, and perhaps a call back when it is released?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)

```dart
GestureDector(
  onTapDown: (_) => print('down'),
  onTapUp: (_) => print('up'),
  child: Text('click me'),
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to replace my FlatButton widget with an InkWell widget to get the behavior I wanted.